Cannot retrieve secrets from SecretManager of AWS in Angular App
I have as frontend Angular App which has functionality to connect with ActiveMQ and read messages from queue.
To connect with ActiveMQ will be used login and password for ActiveMQ which I would like to get from secret manager from AWS and use them in code.
I dont know exactly what is the right way to do this. My deployment configuration already use secret like this:
  externalSecrets:
    service:
      key: my.test.secrets

here is my code:
I tried to define SecretManagerService which should retrieve secrets by secretName but I was getting error "Error retrieving secret. Credential is missing"
may be there is another way how to retrieve secret values ?
export class SecretManagerService {
  private client: SecretsManagerClient;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new SecretsManagerClient({
      region: 'eu-west-1',
    });
  }

  async getSecret(secretName: string): Promise<string | undefined> {
    try {
      const response = await this.client.send(
        new GetSecretValueCommand({
          SecretId: secretName,
          VersionStage: 'AWSCURRENT',
        })
      );

      return response.SecretString;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving secret', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}

export class MyService {
  constructor(
    private rxStompService: RxStompService,
    private secretManagerService: SecretManagerService) {
  }

  private async initStompService(clientId: string) {
      const secretString = await this.secretManagerService.getSecret(environment.secretName);

      if (!secretString) {
        throw new Error('Failed to retrieve secrets');
      }
      const secret = JSON.parse(secretString);

    const stompConfig = {
      brokerURL: environment.activeMqURL,
      connectHeaders: {
        'client-id': clientId,
        login: secret.login,
        passcode: secret.password,
      },
      heartbeatIncoming: 0,
      heartbeatOutgoing: 20000,
      reconnectDelay: 200,
      debug: (msg: string): void => {
        console.log(new Date(), msg);
      },
    };
    this.rxStompService.configure(stompConfig);
    this.rxStompService.activate();
  }


The SDK is missing AWS credentials. Where is your angular app running and how, e.g. with server side rendering on an EC2 instance?
In general, it is dangerous to have credentials in the frontend. It makes your ActiveMQ public. If this is intended, then you do not need any credentials.
Otherwise I recommend creating a backend for accessing the queue.
